# Updating Meteor.users

Tags: meteor

I've created a form for users to update their profiles. When I submit the form I'm receiving a [403] error.

`Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID.`

My question is, if I'm going to use `Meteor.users.allow`, where - in what file/directory - do I write this code?

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: could you post your code ?? It will make more sense figure us out.

Answer (score 18):

The error you're getting is not a result of your allow/deny rules. You would get a straight 'Access Denied' error if it were.

When updating your users (as well as having the correct `allow` rules in place) you need to update your user by their `_id`- especially if they are being updated on the client end.

So instead of

```
Meteor.users.update({name: "etc"}, {$set:..});
```

You need to split it in two, one to get the `_id` and then one to update your document on that.

```
var user = Meteor.users.findOne({name: 'etc'});

Meteor.users.update({_id: user._id}, {$set:..});
```

The rule is on the client you can only use `_id` to find the document when updating.

Comment: Thanks @Akshat. I read the error, but I was being stubborn, thinking there was a way around it.

One more question, where would be a good place to put my `allow` rules for the `users` collection?

Comment: You need to make sure they run on the server, so in a js file in the root directory or the `/server` directory.

Comment: you don't need the explicit `Meteor.users.findOne();` call here. `Meteor.users.update( { _id: Meteor.userId() }, { $set: { 'profile.online': true }} );` is enough as you can invoke `Meteor.userId()` right away.

Comment: @MarkusGattol I think the OP's case he was using some other way to find the user without using the `_id` field