# how to update a Mongo.db collection in meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection that I need to update when the user presses a button.
I just need to change one variable to another.

In the console, this line of code works:

```
  db.users.update({username : "Jack"},{age : 13, username : "Jack"});
```

But when I put in this code:

```
Template.body.events({
'click #updateAge' = function() {
         {
              alert();
              db.users.update({username : "Jack"},{age : 13, username : "Jack"});
         }
    }

})
```

into my JavaScript file for Meteor.js, it doesn't do anything at all (I don't get an error message, and I see the alert, but the update just doesn't work).

I've read through the Meteor Documentation on updating, but I just can't seem to get it to work.
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Does just using users.update(...) work? There is a solution like this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016149/meteor-mongo-finding-and-updating-certain-elements-in-a-collection

Comment: I think Mongo needs a selector, which is why I have my {username : "Jack"} but they are using the same thing I am...  Unless, do you mean the Meteor tag in front of the users.update?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the problem.

Since I defined my database in my lib.js file

`users = new Meteor.collection("users");`

I don't need to put a db in front of the `db.users.update({_id : "Jack"},{...})`.  I also need to find the document using the given mongo `_id`, not the identifier `"username"`.

so the appropriate code would be

```
users.update({_id : "Jack"},{$set:{age : 13, username : "Jack"}});
```

Comment: may i know whats the use of `$set` here while Updating document ?, and what if we dont know `_id` i mean if we are selecting dynamially ?

Comment: It's been a long time since I used meteor or mongo, but if I remember correctly $set will update only the specified values (age and username in this case).  If there is another value, such as "gender", $set won't erase that since we didn't define "gender" here.

Answer (score 0):

In mongodb, you will have to use an update operator(for ex: `$set`). Otherwise, your document will overwritten by the update object you are passing(*I am not sure that's what you want*). I think, its works same in meteor. So, you will have to do something like this:

```
Meteor.users.update({username : "Jack"},{$set: {age : 13}});
```

Comment: Still not working, is the Meteor tag in front of users.update required?

Comment: Looks like you need it. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027893/updating-meteor-users

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the problem as you've stated you do not get a error message but to be sure: have you already allowed the user to update documents in the user collection?

Something like:

(in collections/permissions.js)

```
user.allow({
update: function (userId) {
    // the user must be logged in to allow updates
    return (userId != null);
}
```

})